# Does this statement require a comma or two?

Tags: commas

> I had no intention to dismiss XYZ right off the bat and I haven't.

Additionally, is "and I haven't" correctly used? As I was talking about something I did in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Your tenses are correct here.

The most natural punctuation is probably

> I had no intention to dismiss XYZ right off the bat, and I haven't.

There should definitely be no comma after "intention".

There is a very small chance that a comma after "XYZ" might be appropriate. "I had no intention to dismiss XYZ, right off the bat…" would mean "From the very beginning, I didn't intend to dismiss XYZ". (I think that's not what you mean. What you probably mean is "I never intended to dismiss XYZ immediately".)

However, I would probably emphasise the final clause. In spoken English, the emphasis on the word "haven't" is enough to convey your meaning, but in writing I think the following is more fluent:

> I had no intention to dismiss XYZ right off the bat, and indeed I haven't.